# Android Map Overlays not working properly

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, itemizedoverlay

I had it working until i tried to combine it with xml that is parsed from my webpage. No markers get added, yet i get no errors. Below is the new code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

LocationBasedServicesV2.java :

```
private MapView myMap;
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    try {
           URL url = new URL("MySiteGoesHere");
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();
            tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
        .setMessage(e.toString())   
        .setTitle("error")   
        .setCancelable(true)   
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,   
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}   
           })   
        .show(); 
    }


    initMap();
    //initLocationManager();
}
private void initMap() {
    myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);

    View zoomView = myMap.getZoomControls();
    LinearLayout myzoom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myzoom);
    myzoom.addView(zoomView);
    myMap.displayZoomControls(true);

}
/*private void initLocationManager() {
    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
            createAndShowMyItemizedOverlay(newLocation);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }
    };
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);
}*/
public void createAndShowMyItemizedOverlay(int Lat,int Long) {
    //int Lat2;
    //int Long2;
    //Lat2 = Integer.parseInt(Lat);
    //Long2 = Integer.parseInt(Long);
    List overlays = myMap.getOverlays();
    GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(Lat,Long);
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon
            .getIntrinsicHeight());
    MyItemizedOverlay overlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(icon);
    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "My Location", null);
    overlay.addItem(item);
    myMap.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    myMap.getController().animateTo(geopoint);

        }
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
 }
```

MyItemizedOverlay.java:

```
 public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
private List items;
private Drawable marker;
public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    items = new ArrayList();
    marker = defaultMarker;
}
@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
    return (OverlayItem)items.get(index);
}
@Override
public int size() {
    return items.size();
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    boundCenterBottom(marker);
}
public void addItem(OverlayItem item) {
    items.add(item);
    populate();
}
 }
```

ExampleHandler.java:

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{

    private boolean in_lat = false;
    private boolean in_long = false;
    private boolean in_retailer = false;

    private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();


    public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
            return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Nothing to do
    }


    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("Lat")) {
                    this.in_lat = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("Long")) {
                this.in_long = true;
            }

    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
           if (localName.equals("Lat")) {
                    this.in_lat = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("Long")) {
                this.in_long = false;}
            else if (localName.equals("Retailer")) {
                this.in_retailer = false;}
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            if(this.in_lat){
            myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));}
            else if(this.in_long){
                myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString2(new String(ch, start,     length));}

}
}
```

ParsedExampleDataSet.Java:

```
public class ParsedExampleDataSet extends LocationBasedServicesV2 {
private String extractedString = null;
private String OLDextractedString = null;
String Long;
String Lat;
Double Long2;
Double Lat2;
int Lat3;
int Long3;

public void setExtractedString(String extractedString) {
        Long = extractedString;
        Long2 = Double.parseDouble(Long);
        Long3 =  (int) (Long2 * 1E6);
        /*if (OLDextractedString != null){
        this.extractedString = OLDextractedString + extractedString + ',' ; 
    }
    else
    {
        this.extractedString = extractedString + ',' ;
    }
        OLDextractedString = this.extractedString;*/
}
public void setExtractedString2(String extractedString) {
   Lat = extractedString;
   Lat2 = Double.parseDouble(Lat);
   Lat3 =  (int) (Lat2 * 1E6);
   createAndShowMyItemizedOverlay(Lat3,Long3);
   /*if (OLDextractedString != null){
     * 
        this.extractedString = OLDextractedString + extractedString + '\n' ;    
    }
    else
    {
        this.extractedString = OLDextractedString + '\n' + extractedString  ;
    }
    OLDextractedString = this.extractedString;*/
}
   public int parseInt(){

       return Lat3;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to check: your method createAndShowMyItemizedOverlay() appears to be only called when the ParsedExampleDataSet is created - and this is created in a try/catch where you're swallowing any exception. This could be the reason why your not seeing an error and why it stopped working when you started trying to parse the xml.

Comment: You were exactly right. The original problem was that it couldnt parse the Lat correctly. I have now updated the code into which i thought would work but for some reason it doesnt. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. Above is the updated code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So i have found the srouce of the NULLPointerException, it turns out that for some reason whenever "mymap" is being referenced it is returning null for mymap any ideas why?